# Why do individual terms go till infinity in a generating function even when a limit is specified?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

For example:
What is the generating function for: x1+x2+x3=12; x1>=2; 3<=x<=6; x3<=9

Why does the first term go till infinity instead of x^12.
(x^2 + x^3 + x^4 +....)(x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6)(1 + x + x^2 + ...)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In working with generating functions, we usually seek the more general solution to a problem.  So rather then finding the number of solutions in integers to 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 =12$$
subject to whatever constraints you have, we would usually prefer to find the generating function of the number of solutions to
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 =r$$
where $r$ is an unspecified integer. 
Once we have the solution to the more general problem, the original problem is then just the special case $r = 12$.

Why seek the more general solution?  Well, it's good to have the solution to a more general problem.  And often the more general problem is easier to solve.

Comment: Makes sense. Since 'r' can vary upto infinity, we take the terms till coefficient of infinity. Thanks!!